# zoho email imap connection using node-imap is getting timeout in aws instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, imap, zoho

I am using node-imap to connect and read zoho mail from my nodejs application, I am getting timeout err as below in AWS ubuntu instance, But in my local it is getting connected fine.

```
    { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  source: 'socket' }
```

1. Do i need to open any socket in AWS to use imap?
2. If so how i can do that?

You help regarding this is highly appreciated.
Thanks.